# Python: The opposite of `datetime.date.isocalendar()`

Tags: python, date, iso

The `datetime` module provides a method `date.isocalendar` that, given a date, returns it in the format `([year], [week], [weekday])`. How do I go backwards? Given a `([year], [week], [weekday])` tuple, how can I get a `date` object?

Comment: Hot d*mn, this is more complicated than I thought at first. Week 1 is the week that contains the calendar year's first *Thursday*!?!

Comment: Haha. Welcome to the world of calendars, enjoy your stay :)

Comment: I have a nagging suspicion that there's a very good reason why this function is not in the Standard Library :)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** Found question with solution:
[What's the best way to find the inverse of datetime.isocalendar()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304256/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-inverse-of-datetime-isocalendar)

My solution had mistakes.  On googling saw previous question which upon testing below worked.  (See top answered question in above link for definition of `iso_to_gregorian` ).  (Basically find iso year start date and then use timedelta to find current date from day and week number.

```
for i in range(-10000,10000,1):
    x = datetime.datetime.today().date() + datetime.timedelta(i)
    x_iso = datetime.datetime.isocalendar(x)
    assert iso_to_gregorian(*x_iso) == x
```

Comment: Try this on `1999,1,1`. You'll be a week off...

Comment: Yup as soon as I tested it I realized I had mistakes.  Discussion on 2008 stackoverflow question goes through the reasons the edge cases weren't working and has a relatively simple solution.

Comment: +1 for finding the right answer :)

Comment: wow, that's ugly.