# Get date from ISO week number in Python

Tags: python, iso, week-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What’s the best way to find the inverse of datetime.isocalendar()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304256/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-inverse-of-datetime-isocalendar)

I have an ISO 8601 year and week number, and I need to translate this to the date of the first day in that week (Monday). How can I do this?

[datetime.strptime()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) takes both a `%W` and a `%U` directive, but neither adheres to the ISO 8601 weekday rules that [datetime.isocalendar()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isocalendar) use.

**Update:** [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#datetime) supports the `%G`, `%V` and `%u` directives also present in libc, allowing this one-liner:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2011 22 1', '%G %V %u')
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 30, 0, 0)
```

**Update 2**: [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisocalendar) added the `fromisocalendar()` method, which is even more intuitive:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromisocalendar(2011, 22, 1)
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 30, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Why not elegant? The other options you'll find through google are even more ugly.

Comment: I found a related question with a nice answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304256/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-inverse-of-datetime-isocalendar

Comment: I see mention of a %V directive in PHP strftime() and also libc strptime() but apparently Python doesn't implement it. I went with the solution in the link I posted above.

Comment: @ErikCederstrand: Thank you for your post! I am using Python 3.8.8 but when I tried running `datetime.fromisocalendar(2011, 22, 1)`, I got the following error message: `AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromisocalendar'`. I ran `pip install datetime` and it appears that it installed version 4.7. Do you know what could be causing the issue?

Comment: Figured it out! I had to put `datetime.datetime.fromisocalendar(2011, 22, 1)`.

Comment: The `datetime` module referenced above is the one from the standard library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), not https://pypi.org/project/DateTime/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

%W takes the first Monday to be in week 1 but ISO defines week 1 to contain 4 January. So the result from

```
datetime.strptime('2011221', '%Y%W%w')
```

is off by one iff the first Monday and 4 January are in different weeks.
The latter is the case if 4 January is a Friday, Saturday or Sunday.
So the following should work:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
def tofirstdayinisoweek(year, week):
    ret = datetime.strptime('%04d-%02d-1' % (year, week), '%Y-%W-%w')
    if date(year, 1, 4).isoweekday() > 4:
        ret -= timedelta(days=7)
    return ret
```

Answer (score 75):

With the [isoweek module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/isoweek/) you can do it with:

```
from isoweek import Week
d = Week(2011, 40).monday()
```

Comment: This is definitely the most practical way to go, especially if you are doing a lot of manipulation of ISO weeks.

Comment: SInce Python 3.8, the original question can be answered easily without dependencies for a given datetime object: `current_iso_day_number = datetime_obj.isocalendar()[2]; return datetime_obj.replace(days=(current_iso_day_number - 1))`. This subtracts enough days to get the `datetime` object to ISO weekday 1. (I had to answer here since the question is closed.)