# Strptime Weeks Error

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I'm writing some scripts that require manipulating what week of the year it is.
My inputs are in the form `YYYYWW`, such as `'201435'`.

During my attempts to use `strptime` it, for some reason, defaults to the first of the year. For example:

```
import datetime
test = '201435'
test = datetime.datetime.strptime(test,'%Y%U')
print(test)
```

outputs

```
2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

I'm not sure why it's doing so. Using the `time` module or replacing `%U` with `%W` has the exact same result.

Comment: See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5884021/2744166

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read Note 6 in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> When used with the `strptime()` method, `%U` and `%W` are only used in
>   calculations when the day of the week and the year are specified.

Therefore, as you don't specify a day in that week, the week number is ignored and you get the first of the year. To fix that, add a day:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2014350', '%Y%U%w')
                                    # ^ here   ^ and here
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 31, 0, 0)
```

Comment: My apologies for not catching that, thanks for the help!