# Finding Month from Day, Week and Year Python

Tags: python, mysql

I can not figure out how to take the year, day and week to return the month. Right now I am just trying to develop a Python Script that will do this. The goal after finishing this script is to use it for a Spark SQL Query to find the month since in my data I am given a day, year and week in each row.

As of now my python code looks like so. This code only works for the statement I have into the print(getmonth(2, 30 ,2018) returning 7. I have tried other dates and the output is only "None". I have tried variables also, but no success there.

```
import datetime

def month(day, week, year):
    for month in range(1,13):
        try:
            date = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)
        except ValueError:
            iso_year, iso_weeknum, iso_weekday = date.isocalendar()
            if iso_weeknum == week:
                return date.month
print(getmonth(2, 30, 2018))


#iso_(year,weeknum,weekday) are the classes for ISO. Year is 1-9999, weeknum is 0-52 or 53, and weekday is 0-6
#isocaldenar is a tuple (year, week#, weekday)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `def getmonth(day, week, year):` or `print(month(28, 30, 2018))` ?
Your code returns `None` for `print(month(28, 30, 2018))` as well.

Comment: `if` reached only if exception happened, you should move it to `try` block or unindent it by one level

Comment: @Deuce def getmonth( day,week, year) also returns none

Comment: @Deuce I see. It should be moved as well. There should only be `pass` or `print("error")` in `except` block to satisfy syntax rules.

Comment: I don't understand the input, how is day 28 and week is 30?, week makes sense as it is the 30th week of the year, but the 28 is eluding me

Comment: @NickA I think that may have been a mistake by me. I was messing with days on a 1-365 base and just forgot to change it back from 0-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your questions, but i think datetime will work... [sorce: Get date from ISO week number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5882405/2938861):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> day = 28
>>> week = 30
>>> year = 2018
>>> t = datetime.strptime('{}_{}_{}{}'.format(day,week,year,-0), '%d_%W_%Y%w')
>>> t.strftime('%W')
'30'
>>> t.strftime('%m')
'07'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution can be created using the `pendulum` library. As in your code, loop through month numbers, create dates, compare the weeks for these dates against the desired date. If found halt the loop; if the date is not seen then exit the loop with, say, a -1.

```
>>> import pendulum
>>> for month in range(1,13):
...     date = pendulum.create(2018, month, 28)
...     if date.week_of_year == 30:
...         break
... else:
...     month = -1
...     
>>> month
7
>>> date
<Pendulum [2018-07-28T00:00:00+00:00]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force method that loops through the days of the year (It expects the day as Monday being 0 and Sunday being 6, it also returns the Month 0 indexed, January being 0 and December being 11):

```
import datetime

def month(day, week, year):
    #Generate list of No of days of the month
    months = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    if((year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or year % 400 == 0): months[1] += 1

    #ISO wk1 of the yr is the first wk with a thursday, otherwise it's wk53 of the previous yr
    currentWeek = 1 if day < 4 else 0

    #The day that the chosen year started on
    currentDay = datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1).weekday()

    #Loop over every day of the year
    for i in range(sum(months)):
        #If the week is correct and day is correct you're done
        if day == currentDay and week == currentWeek:
            return months.index(next(filter(lambda x: x!=0, months)))

        #Otherwise, go to next day of wk/next wk of yr
        currentDay = (currentDay + 1) % 7
        if currentDay == 0:
            currentWeek += 1

        #And decrement counter for current month
        months[months.index(next(filter(lambda x: x!=0, months)))]-=1

print(month(2, 30, 2018)) # 6 i.e. July
```

`months.index(next(filter(lambda x: x!=0, months)))` is used to get the first month of that we haven't used all of the days of, i.e. the month you're currently in.