# How to get a year-week text in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, week-number

I have a table which contains information on the number of changes done on a particular day. I want to add a text field to it in the format `YYYY-WW` (e. g. `2022-01`) which indicates the week number of the day. I need this information to determine in what week the total number of changes was the highest.

How can I determine the week number in Python?

Below is the code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2600864/399457):

```
week_nr = day.isocalendar().week
year = day.isocalendar().year
week_nr_txt = "{:4d}-{:02d}".format(year, week_nr)
```

At a first glance it seems to work, but I am not sure that `week_nr_txt` will contain year-week tuple according to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) standard.

Will it?

If not how do I need to change my code in order to avoid any week-related errors (example see below)?

Example of a week-related error: In year `y1` there are 53 weeks and the last week spills over into the year `y1+1`.

The correct year-week tuple is `y1-53`. But I am afraid that my code above will result in `y2-53` (`y2=y1+1`) which is wrong.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882405/get-date-from-iso-week-number-in-python) might be relevant. Also, pandas seems to support the ISO 8601 standard, e.g. see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.isocalendar.html).

Comment: Did you try your code? I tried `datetime.date(2020, 12, 30).isocalendar()` and got `datetime.IsoCalendarDate(year=2020, week=53, weekday=3)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I try to give my answer.  You can easily use **datetime** python module like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime(year, month, day)

# And formating the date time object like :
date.strftime('%Y-%U')
```

Then you will have the year and wich week the total information changes