# Python - Determine

Tags: python, calendar, python-datetime

I am trying to identify the month number from a given week and year number (both are user inputs). The script needs to be written in python. 
eg - 1) Yr 2017, Wk 12 results in Month# 3
2) Yr 2017, Wk 32 results in Month#8 and so on

I am a newbie and searched for all date time examples, still no clue. Any ideas? Would really appreciate the help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What month do you want if the week spans two months? For example, year 2017, week 5 (January 30, 2017 - February 5, 2017).

Comment: Related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304256/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-inverse-of-datetime-isocalendar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087314/get-date-from-week-number

Comment: which week numbering scheme? (iso?)

Comment: Good question Rob. If I use iso scheme for calendar, will this still matter?

Answer (score 0):

As we know the numbers of days in each month of a given year, and the number of days that span `w` weeks (`w*7`) it is sufficient to sum the days of each month until the result is greater than `w*7`, counting the number of months used in the sum. If we used say `n` months, the number you want is `n`

We can know if the year is a leap year as the following demonstrates.

```
import calendar
print calendar.isleap(2017)
```

Comment: What if the Wk1 has only 1 week? Does this still apply?

Comment: Allow me to correct myself. The number you want is n. I shall update my answer.

Comment: So if you want the month of week 1, the sum would halt on the first month (as 30>7*1), so week 1 belongs to month 1.

Comment: Note that this assumes that we want the number of the month that contains the last day of the given week. As Rob commented the behaviour you expect when a week is part of two months is not specified.